# Exception using POI to set watermark in doc file

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, doc

I'm using poi-3.9, to set watermark in .doc

Here is my code:

```
public void setWarterMark()
{
    String filesname = "Example1.doc";
    try
    {

        XWPFDocument xDoc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(filesname));
        XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy xFooter = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(xDoc);
        xFooter.createWatermark("My Watermark");
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The console show:

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:41)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:120)
at com.avi.Test.ReadDoc.main(ReadDoc.java:46)
```

Comment: Still waiting for solution

Comment: Where does your original .docx file come from? If you open the original in Word and do a Save-As, does that new file work properly with POI?

Comment: @Gagravarr: I am using doc file and my file in current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.doc` format, hence the exception occurs. `XWPFDocument` works with `.docx` format. Try changing the format and hopefully it will work.